# command line find/replace help

Tags: macos, command-line, shell, find-and-replace

I've got a set of 5000+ files that I need to do a simple search and replace in. I have been doing it in a text editor (EditPlus) by opening 500 files at a time, doing a global search/replace, saving all, closing, etc. But, that's taking literally hours to do and it's boring and tedious and I already have done it once today and need to do it again because all the files got refreshed. Is there a way to do this via the Bash command line? Here's the details:

Find `onchange="document.location ='/products/view.html/view/'+this.value"`

Replace it with `onchange="alert('Not implemented')" style="display: none"`

All of the files have a .HTM extension, but they are nested in several sub directories.

EDIT - I'm on a Mac and would prefer a *nix based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base command for you case looks like this:

```
sed -i 's|oldvalue|newvalue|g' file1 file2 file3
```

If all your file are in the directory `~/foo/bar/`, what you want to do is:

```
cd '~/foo/bar/'
find . -type f | xargs sed -i "" "s|onchange=\"document.location ='/products/view.html/view/'+this.value\"|onchange=\"alert\('Not implemented'\)\" style=\"display: none\"|g"
```

EDIT: the glob (`*` as file name) can be problematic with very very much files and don't go in the child directories. In this case, change the last line.

EDIT 2: with BSD sed (the one used on MacOS X) `-i` needs an argument. BTW using `xargs`. Thanks to @Dennis Williamson

Comment: The questioner mentioned a Windows-based text editor, so my guess is that a windows solution is needed. Yours will probably work if cygwin or a similar environment is installed.

Comment: @Doug Harris He asked: "Is there a way to do this via the Bash command line?" seams to be a mixed environment.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion. I'm on a Mac, but I had previously been remoted in to a Windows machine and was using EditPlus. (EditPlus has a superior Find/Replace interface over TextMate)

Comment: Question about the above solution: I'm getting an error saying "syntax error near unexpected token `('". I took a guess that it may have been the parentheses and tried escaping them, but that just resulted in what appeared to be a line waiting for input - just a " >"

Comment: aha. My mistake.

Comment: @ Chrisbloom7 sorry, bash quote problem: `sed -i "s|onchange=\"document.location ='/products/view.html/view/'+this.value\"|onchange=\"alert('Not implemented')\" style=\"display: none\"|g" *`

Comment: That just results in a few thousand lines of `sed: 1: "./APPLICATION_NOTES.HTM": invalid command code .`

Comment: here's what I'm running: `find . -type f -name "*.HTM" | while read f; do sed -i "s|onchange=\"document.location ='/products/view.html/view/'+this.value\"|onchange=\"alert('Not implemented')\" style=\"display: none\"|g" "$f" ; done`

Comment: Actually, this might explain it: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=95246 Trying it with some of the variants mentioned there

Comment: @Chrisbloom7: On OS X, `sed` requires a backup extension when using the `-i` option: `sed -i .bak '...'`. Also, `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ... sed ...` instead of the `while` loop.

Comment: I didn't want any backups (I already had the original content backed up elsewhere), so this worked perfectly for me: `find . -type f -name "*.HTM" | while read f; do sed -i "" "s|onchange=\"document.location ='/products/view.html/view/'+this.value\"|onchange=\"alert('Not implemented')\" style=\"display: none\"|g" "$f" ; done`

Comment: This doesn't work with spacing in filenames. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143171/how-can-i-use-xargs-to-copy-files-that-have-spaces-and-quotes-in-their-names has an answer which pipes sed 's/.*/"&"/' before xargs that deals.

Answer (score 2):

Since EditPlus is a Windows editor i'm guessing you want a Windows shell solution.

You can get sed variants for Windows, but here's a [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) solution that recursively finds all *.HTM files, replaces "this" with "that", then saves the file.

```
gci -Include *.HTM -Recurse | % {
  (gc $_) -replace "this","that" | sc -path $_ }
```

Using your strings makes things a bit more tortured, since you have embedded double- and single-quotes, along with regular expression characters. The quotes are escaped with backticks (`) and the regex characters with backslashes (\).

```
gci -Include temp*.HTM -Recurse | % {
  (gc $_) -replace "onchange=`"document\.location `
  =`'/products/view\.html/view/`'\+this\.value",`
  "onchange=`"alert(`'Not implemented`')`" style=`"display: `
  none`"" | sc -path $_ }
```

Powershell is included with Windows 7, and can be downloaded for XP and above.

There's a [vbscript single-file solution at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe/127567#127567) i posted in response to "Is there any sed like utility for cmd.exe?" That question contains many answers with suggestions for Windows command-line sed solutions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. See my comment below - I'm on a Mac and do want to use a Bash or other *nix command line utility.

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 - oh gotcha, i saw the EditPlus but missed the Bash.